# nginx .jpg and .jpeg not found in / but are found everywhere else

Tags: nginx, jpeg, scgi

I'm new to nginx and I like it.
I'm putting up a few scgi feeds, and some static content.
After creating a home page hierarchy under /home, I went to move it to /.
But when I put it there the .jpg and .jpeg images were coming back 404.

sitename.com/test.gif is found just fine.

sitename.com/test.jpg is 404

but creating a a subdirectory, and copying test.jpg work.

sitename.com/subdirectory/jpg is fine.

I'm running with pretty empty config files as they were installed under Ubuntu 18.

I'd REALLY like to know what's going on here, and why top level .jpg/.jpeg files are doing this.

I know I could create a location directive as follows:

```
location ~ \.(jpg|jpeg)$ {
         root  /real/location/of/my/home/;
}
```

But that breaks access to .jpg/jpeg files in the scgi locations served from other roots.

Answer (score 0):

I found it!  It wasn't the jpg/jpeg suffix.  It was the filename!

I have a /wdc location that is an scgi script.
A file in / that begins wdc for example /wdc-face.jpg goes through to scgi.

Many of the nginx example give locations without trailing slashes. But I think that a trailing slash is what people should be encouraged to use by default